# Describing a group of windows?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, architecture

I'm unsure of the **most readily recognizable term** among normal people to describe a group of windows in a building.

Here's an example of the type of architectural feature I have in mind. In this photo there are five distinct 'groups' of windows which I'm trying to describe:

[image]

[image]

<sub>([UK parliament building](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/news/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/London.jpg))</sub>

Using the desired term I might say something like:

> "Please look at the 3rd XXXX of windows from the left..."

Note that from a construction point of view each of those five is made up of multiple frames, pieces of glass (or "glazing units"), etc. but that lower-level of detail is *not* what I am trying to describe.

Thoughts so far:

- The first term that came to mind was that each is an "array" - but I am probably biased by familiarity with that term from computer programming and it might be too obscure. However it does seem to capture the regularity of their layout.
- The second idea is to call them each a "bank" of windows but the Google definition states it is things "grouped together in rows" which may not be correct - column groups also exist. (This may be too literal of a concern).

Again, being technical correct in an architectural sense is distinctly secondary to the meaning most people would infer from the term.

Comment: as there isn't an actual name, can you provide an example sentence, with how you want to use this word.

Comment: and what distinguishes these 5 from the 5 next to them? as the building has 100s of windows

Comment: @WendyG re: example, good suggestion - done, if it helps

Comment: @WendyG how to distinguish them is a good question. In most cases I am thinking of the groups I'm trying to refer to would have a consistent internal pattern. Like 5x2, 2x2, as in the example in the photo. Though this might not always be strictly required it is typical.

Comment: In the picture, there are 5 _windows_, not _groups of windows_. So, your statement will be `"Please look at the 3rd window from the left..."`

Comment: @alwayslearning I agree having re-read the question. Just because the window frames are stone not wood doesn't change that.

Comment: @alwayslearning that may be subjective... the windows in the example photo are relatively huge, and if you were inside that building they might appear to be distinct. I realize the photo gives a poor sense of scale.

Comment: @DaveInCaz, in that case, perhaps you have a different picture in your mind than the one presented. Each of the 5 _groups_ in your picture are _groups of window panes_ (not windows themselves), so there are 5 [paned windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paned_window). The huge size of a window pane does not make it a window in its own right.

Comment: @alwayslearning I added a zoom in of one of them, hopefully to clarify. Each of the five in the first image are not panes, but themselves each huge windows made up of multiple panes. It is not the panes I'm interested in, but the groups of windows.

Comment: They are called **bay.** Check  Bay (3) of [oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bay).

Comment: @Ubihatt I think "bay" has a slightly more specific meaning, in that the group of windows in a "bay window" will project outwards from the wall. A group of windows within the "plane" of the wall would not be a bay, I don't think.

Comment: @DaveInCaz search in-line with "tracery".

Comment: @Ubihatt sorry but I don't think I understand... there is no word "tracery" on that page. Can you clarify please?

Comment: @DaveInCaz here on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracery). You may find something :)

Comment: A **bay** is the architectural term for a vertical division of a building around a window 
or set of windows even if it's flat. See [definition 2 here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bay_(architecture)). It typically relates to the unit of construction of a building, e.g. there may be vaulting divided in ways that matches the windows, or supporting pillars or walls arranged in between windows. (But it's an architectural term so doesn't fit the demand for a layperson's term.)

Comment: "Group of windows" is probably the best term for "normal people".

Answer (score 2):

I think a [row](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/row#h3-anchor) of windows would be most recognizable. People would infer that the windows are horizontally side-by-side.

Another word that comes to mind is [clump](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clump), but that could mean vertical and horizontal. You could specify it and say that: Along each floor, windows are clumped together in groups of 5.

To go along with the updated example,

> "Please look at the 3rd clump of windows from the left..."

Comment: +1 for clump alone.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you say:

> Note that from a construction point of view each of those five is made up of multiple frames, pieces of glass (or "glazing units"), etc. but that lower-level of detail is not what I am trying to describe.

I think the common phrasing you're looking for is *window* ***panes***.

---

For the sake of argument, let's say that a *window* is whatever single piece of hardware that is delivered and installed. Let's also say that we have four windows, each with three vertically aligned window panes, that are installed next to each other. We then have four windows. But next to *those* four windows, separated by brick, cement, or another building feature, is another four windows.

In *this* case, the use of *arrays* or *banks* becomes more understandable.

Graphically, it would look like this, where each [] is a single unit that was delivered and installed—and which contains three vertically aligned *panes* of glass:

[][][][]      [][][][]      [][][][]

[][][][]      [][][][]      [][][][]

[][][][]      [][][][]      [][][][]

Or, with an actual picture:

[image: windows]

The way I would describe this is as follow:

> A 3x3 grid of four-window **groups**.

- I'm saying *grid* only because that's a common way of expressing the geometry of this kind of layout. In the phrasing you introduced, it would be *array*.
- I'm using the word *group* (or *grouping*) to describe each set of four horizontally adjacent windows. In the phrasing you introduced, it would be *banks*.

In your phrasing, you had an array *of* window banks. In my phrasing, it's a grid of window groups.

Or, if you don't like *group*, you could use *set*, which I also used when I said that a window group described "each set of four horizontally adjacent windows."

Additionally, you can say either *a window group* or *a group of windows*, depending on which sounds better given the surrounding text of the sentence.

---

In short, returning to the sentence in your question, I would say:

> "Please look at the 3rd group of windows from the left . . ."

Or, if I were describing something from the example I provided:

> Please look at the top-left group of windows.

Comment: I’m not convinced.  I would have said each [] was a pane.  And [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pane) agrees: *a single sheet of glass in a window or door.*. Actually I’m not sure if you’re saying what I’m saying or not. Now that I look the [] are each made up of three panes.

Comment: @Jim A pane of glass is a single sheet of glass. My [] is a poor graphical example—but I described it before using that character. Look at the picture itself. There are three panes of glass arranged vertically. That's the *unit* that's delivered to a customer and called a *window*.

Comment: Ok so I think we agree on what a pane is. But OP is asking about the groups of panes which I would just call “a window”.

Comment: I would say there are 9 windows in the TGIF photo where each window is a multi-pane window with 12 panes of glass.

Comment: @Jim That's possible—I couldn't say unless I examined the windows directly. But that's not how I described the scenario. ;) In my *description* of the picture, I said "Let's also say that we have four windows, each with three vertically aligned window panes, that are installed next to each other."